How to reference a list of columns in a variable for summarization in Kusto?
I'm working with Kusto Query Language (KQL) and I want to reference a list of columns in one variable for summarization, instead of specifying each column individually. Here's an example of what I have:
let data = datatable(Category: string, Category2: string)
[
    'A', 'X',
    'A', 'X',
    'A', 'X',
    'B', 'Y',
    'B', 'Y',
    'B', 'Y',
    'B', 'Y',
    'C', 'Z',
    'C', 'Z',
    'C', 'Z',
    'C', 'Z',
    'C', 'T'
];
data
| summarize count() by Category, Category2

I want to achieve the same result by referencing the columns from a variable, something like this:
let data = datatable(Category: string, Category2: string)
[
    'A', 'X',
    'A', 'X',
    'A', 'X',
    'B', 'Y',
    'B', 'Y',
    'B', 'Y',
    'B', 'Y',
    'C', 'Z',
    'C', 'Z',
    'C', 'Z',
    'C', 'Z',
    'C', 'T'
];
let columns = pack_array('Category', 'Category2');
data
| summarize count() by columns

However, I get the following error:
Summarize group key '' is of a 'dynamic' type. Please use an explicit cast (for example, 'summarize ... by tostring()') as grouping by a 'dynamic' type is not supported.


Is there a way to achieve this in KQL, or do I need to specify each column individually? Any help or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated!

You cannot use that way if you don't want to add all columns name in summarize then you can use something like KQL query below:
let ri_table = datatable(Rith_cat1: string, Rith_cat2: string)
[
  'A', 'X',
  'A', 'X',
  'A', 'X',
  'B', 'Y',
  'B', 'Y',
  'B', 'Y',
  'B', 'Y',
  'C', 'Z',
  'C', 'Z',
  'C', 'Z',
  'C', 'Z',
  'C', 'T'
];
ri_table
| extend r_cols = pack_array(Rith_cat1, Rith_cat2)
| summarize count() by tostring(r_cols)

Output:

Fiddle.

We don't get context from the question if the array ["C", "T"] is the same as ["T", "C"] for the purposes of the analysis. If they are the same, then the category array should be also sorted by modifying the line to | extend r_cols = array_sort_asc(pack_array(Rith_cat1, Rith_cat2))
